# Cppdepend C++ linux base

Tags: c++, linux, clang, code-metrics, cppdepend

I'm trying to generate code metrics for a C++ project which is *not* a Visual Studio one, rather it was written on Linux.

I tried the Project Maker and followed the steps except for the last part (After adding the source files, you can specify the project properties).  I did not know what to input. So, I proceeded and when starting the Analysis it gives so many clang parsing errors such as

> "string" file not found at "path/xyx.hpp"
>   fstream file not found at "path/ii.hpp"

though I can see in `xyx.hpp` that there is a line `#include <string>`

Answer (score 1):

From the projectmaker configuration you have to specify the include path where the stl library exists. For that right click the project in projectmaker choose properties and added the include path directories separated by ;

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Can you please tell me how can I export a report from the CppDepend? I don't have any rules of my own, I just need the analysis to be exported into excel sheet or anything that I can parse else than HTML report.

Comment: If you need to parse the result you can use the xml files generated after the analysis, you can find them where the report is generated.

Comment: what is the file name that I can parse that has the metrics?